# How to: Make JWT-authenticated requests to the Wordpress API

Tags: rest-api, authentication

This is not really a question but a guide on how to make authenticated requests to the Wordpress API using JWT. I'm writing this as a reminder to myself and for those who may need some help with the same topic.

Comment: You should format this as a question, then post the solution as an actual answer. Otherwise it looks like an unanswered question.

Comment: There is also this fine guide https://firxworx.com/blog/wordpress/using-the-wordpress-rest-api-with-jwt-authentication/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Why JWT authentication**

I'm building a site that uses Wordpress as the back-end, and a React+Redux app as the front-end, so I'm pulling all the content in the front-end by making requests to the Wordpress API. Some requests (mainly, POST requests) must be authenticated, which is when I came across JWT.

**What we need**

To use JWT authentication with Wordpress, we first need to install the [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) plugin. As is explained in the plugin's instructions, we also need to modify some core Wordpress files. In particular:

In the .htaccess file included in the Wordpress installation's root folder, we need to add the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

In the wp-config.php file, also included in the Wordpress installation's root folder, we need to add these lines:

```
define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'your-top-secret-key'); // Replace 'your-top-secret-key' with an actual secret key.
define('JWT_AUTH_CORS_ENABLE', true);
```

**Testing to see if JWT is available**

To verify that we can now use JWT, fire up Postman and make a request to the Wordpress API's default 'index':

```
http://example.com/wp-json/
```

A few new endpoints, like `/jwt-auth/v1` and `/jwt-auth/v1/token` should have been added to the API. If you can find them in the response to the above request, it means JWT is now available.

**Getting the JWT token**

Let's stay in Postman for the moment, and let's request a token to the Wordpress API:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token
```

The response will contain the JWT token, which is an encrypted key that looks something like this:

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODg4OFwvZm90b3Jvb20tbmV4dCIsImlhdCI6MTUyMjU5NzQ1MiwibmJmIjoxNTIyNTk3NDUyLCJleHAiOjE1MjMyMDIyNTIsImRhdGEiOnsidXNlciI6eyJpZCI6IjEifX19.hxaaT9iowAX1Xf8RUM42OwbP7QgRNxux8eTtKhWvEUM

**Making an authenticated request**

Let's try to change the title of a post with an ID of 300 as an example of an authenticated request with JWT.

In Postman, choose POST as the method and type the following endpoint:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/300
```

Choose No Auth in the Authorization tab, and add the following in the Headers tab:

```
'Content-type': 'application/json', 
'Authorization': 'Bearer jwtToken' // Replace jwtToken with the actual token (the encrypted key above)
```

Finally, in the Body tab, select the raw and JSON (application/json) options, then in the editor right below the options type the following:

```
{ "title": "YES! Authenticated requests with JWT work" }
```

Now you can hit SEND. Look in the response tab with all the data about the post that we requested: the value for the title key should now be `YES! Authenticated requests with JWT work`

Comment: How would you distinguish between calls that must be authenticated and such that  don't have to be authenticated in the back-end?

Comment: I'm also building a React app which pulls the posts data from the WordPress database using the WordPress REST API, however, I don't want to have the REST API endpoints publicly available. Is there a way to restrict access to the REST API except for my React app?

Comment: @chris If you want your endpoints to be hidden away from non authorized requests, add them under the namespace jwt_auth, i.e. like so: `register_rest_route( 'jwt-auth/v1', 'your_custom_endpoint ... `. Anything under /jwt-auth/ will need authorization

Comment: @uruk once you have the JWT token, I think you can always send it, so you don't need to distinguish which one is needed and which one is not.

Comment: As I see, this plugin hasn't been updated for so long, is it still safe to use?

Comment: @Lai32290 This plugin looks to be up to date and appears to be based on the plugin mentioned in this question: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-auth/

Comment: @uruk this is how I did distinguish between calls that must be authenticated and such that don't, without plugin: [How to force Authentication on REST API for Password protected page using custom table and fetch() without Plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/391515/how-to-force-authentication-on-rest-api-for-password-protected-page-using-custom/391516#391516)

Answer (score 8):

Complementing @grazianodev's answer, this is how you get your authorization token using cURL:

```
/**
*   Generate a JWT token for future API calls to WordPress
*/
private function getToken() {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://site.localhost/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    # Admin credentials here
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=admin&password=Str0ngPass"); 

    // receive server response ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
    if ($server_output === false) {
        die('Error getting JWT token on WordPress for API integration.');
    }
    $server_output = json_decode($server_output);

    if ($server_output === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        die('Invalid response getting JWT token on WordPress for API integration.');
    }

    if (!empty($server_output->token)) {
        $this->token = $server_output->token; # Token is here
        curl_close ($ch);
        return true;
    } else {
        die('Invalid response getting JWT token on WordPress for API integration.');
    }
    return false;
}
```

After that, send your requests with the header: "Authorization: Bearer $token"

Where $token is the token returned by the getToken() function above.

I personally use the plugin "**Disable REST API and Require JWT / OAuth Authentication**" to restrict API access only with the token above.